# Animate only the "src" alpha attribute of ImageView instead of the entire view

Tags: android, xml, opacity, src

I have an ImageView, initially empty. Its background is set to grey:

```
<ImageView
  android:background="#333" />
```

After I fetch its bitmap from the internets, I want to set it as the src property, but fade it in gracefully. The animation examples I've seen for this do it like:

```
// fade_in.xml
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <alpha
      android:duration="2000"
      android:fromAlpha="0.0"
      android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_interpolator"
      android:toAlpha="1.0" />

</set>
```

but this is animating the opacity of the entire ImageView. It has the effect of first hiding the ImageView before fading it in, so you see a little pop at the start of the animation is the view as first set to alpha=0.

Is there a way to animate the opacity of just the "src" attribute instead of the entire ImageView?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Animations on imageView's source image is tricky and in most cases involve wraping imageView into some ViewGroup, but if all you want to do is animate its alpha (fade in/out), it is very easy to do using a TransitionDrawable:

```
TransitionDrawable transitionDrawable = new TransitionDrawable(new Drawable[]{
       new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT),
       getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.my_image)
   });
imageview.setImageDrawable(transitionDrawable);
transitionDrawable.startTransition(300);
```

Comment: Thanks for this code, wanted to do exactly a simple fadeIn of an Image keeping it's background color.
Since "getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.my_image)" is depricated I replaced it with --> "ResourcesCompat.getDrawable(getResources(), R.drawable.your_drawable, null)" and it works perfectly !

Answer (score 1):

Wrap the `ImageView` inside a `ViewGroup` such as `LinearLayout` which will `wrap_content` and will have all the settings you want to keep visible, such as the background color. Something like this:

```
<LinearLayout 
    android:layout_width='wrap_content' 
    android:layout_height='wrap_content'
    android:background='#ff0000'>
    <ImageView src='@drawable/ic_launcher' 
        android:layout_width='wrap_content'
        android:layout_height='wrap_content'/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Which will result in the following results with an `alpha` of 0.5 and 1 respectively.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You have 2 options:

1) Put a transparent `ImageView` in a gray container (easy). The simplest container is `FrameLayout`.

2) Animate the alpha of the contained image with the [`ImageView.setAlpha(int)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html#setAlpha%28int%29) method. This method takes an integer as parameter, that ranges from 0 (fully transparent) to 255 (fully opaque). To animate a custom property like this, you'll need to use an [`ObjectAnimator`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/animation/ObjectAnimator.html) or [NineOldAndroids](http://nineoldandroids.com/).